# Is there any DLP solution for linux?

Tags: linux, security

I'm looking for a DLP (Data Leak Prevention) solution for linux environments.
I know OpenDLP, but it's only a way to Prevent Clear-text file, and source codes from malicious access.
There are lots of good solutions from Symantec, McAfee, Sophos and etc , But They all work with Windows and there's no Linux agent!

Comment: This term appears to be a made up marking B.S. by firms selling snakeoil designed to separate fools from their money.

Comment: Putting aside the comment above, the OP should really have used [SoftwareRecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) for this.